# Using Paramiko on Windows, SSH to Linux, top command returns nothing

Tags: python, linux, ssh, output, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko in a Python script to ssh to a remote Linux machine.  The connection itself works fine, but when I try to run a specific Linux command, Paramiko returns nothing.  When run directly on the Linux machine, the command returns the output that I want.  My code is as follows:

```
sshapp = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshapp.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
sshapp.load_system_host_keys
sshapp.connect(host,username=user,password=passwd)
stdin,stdout,stderr = appliance.exec_command("top -n2 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'NR==2' | cut -d % -f 1") # grab cpu number as an integer
output = stdout.readlines()
print(output)
```

If I do the same sequence with a simpler command (such as ls -la), the output is returned as expected.  But with the top command given above, the output is empty.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: See if using `top -n1` at least passes data thru. Most versions of `top` don't write directly to std-out, the do some trick of taking over the screen painting. That's how it can "paint" the table, and update the values in "real-time". So you have to figure out how to turn that feature off, or otherwise work around it. GOod luck.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did find a way to make this work.  I added the -b option which causes top to operate in batch mode.  That was enough for it to return the proper value to my script.  Thanks again!

Comment: `man <progname>` is your friend (look for an `examples` section first) ;-) . Glad you got your problem resolved. Good luck to all.